# Do something based on echo text

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, git, shelljs

I am using shelljs to git clone in my node app. I want to only do something once the clone is successful. So wanted to so something like this:

```
shell.exec(`git clone https://myrepo.git; echo "cloned"`);
```

This returns `cloned` once my repo is cloned on Google Cloud functions. How do I do something like this:

```
if echo === 'cloned' {
   //do something
} else {
      //do something else
}
```

Comment: It would probably be simpler to just chain your commands. WIth `git clone https://myrepo.git && echo "cloned"`, the `echo` will not be executed if `git clone` returns an error.

Comment: @RomainValeri, can you give me an example please? Sorry, I am new to this.

Comment: This probably is a valuable starting point for you to read about how to use that function: https://stackabuse.com/executing-shell-commands-with-node-js/

Comment: I would like to point out that you need to add a test condition on the return code for the git command, to make sure that it was successful.  You shouldn't send that "cloned" echo unless it was a fully cloned branch, not act when git terminates badly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this:

```
if (shell.exec(`git clone https://myrepo.git`).code === 0) {
    //do something
} else {
   //do something else
}
```

This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

use && instead of ; like this:

```
shell.exec(`git clone https://myrepo.git && echo "cloned"`);
```

&& means `echo "cloned"` won't be executed until `git clone https://myrepo.git` finish successfully.